# Center a Banner on the bottom of the screen with css

Tags: html, css

I started learning css and I am trying to center a div on the bottom of the screen with. The result should look like this:[image]. This is my code

```
<div class="banner_wrapper">
<div class="banner ">some text</div>
</div>
```

and the css

```
  .banner_wrapper {
     text-align: center;
}
  .banner{
    position: absolute;
    width:70%;
    display: block;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    background: rgba(215, 40, 40, 0.9);
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/varsha19/g4v1qutL/ try this

Answer (score 1):

Position to absolute and translate your div to the center of the page using `transform:translate(-50%, -50%)`; and make bottom:0;

```
.banner_wrapper
{          
          position: absolute;
          left: 50%;
          bottom: 0px;
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          margin: 0 auto;
          background-color:red;
          width:60%;
          height:50px;
          text-align:center;

}
```

```css
.banner_wrapper
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color:red;
  width:60%;
  height:50px;
  text-align:center;
}
.banner
{
  color:white;
  font-size:40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="banner_wrapper">
<div class="banner ">some text</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without changing anything, this should be the best approach:

```css
.banner{
    position: absolute;
    width:70%;
    display: block;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    background: rgba(215, 40, 40, 0.9);
    z-index: 100;
    /* I've just added this last line */
    left: 15%;
}
```

That will work because it will be 15% distant from the left side, then the block will have a size of 70% of the container, and then there will be a remaining 15% on the right, which means that you have your block aligned.

Answer (score 0):

```css
  .banner{
    position: absolute;
    width:70%;
    display: block;
    position:fixed;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    bottom:30px;
    background: rgba(215, 40, 40, 0.9);
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner_wrapper">
<div class="banner ">some text</div>
</div>
```

You should add this :

```
left:0px
right: 0px
margin: 0 auto;
```

And change bottom value

```
bottom: 30px;
```

Comment: This will not work as OP's banner is absolutely positioned

Comment: Forgive me you're correct. Thanks for updating the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's exactly what you are looking for, but here what I got :

I used position static instead of absolute because I think it's more relevant for a "banner" element

```css
.bruce_banner {
  position:fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  width:60vw;
  height:50px;
  left:calc(50% - 30vw);
  border:1px solid black;
  background: #fff;
}

.mainContent {
  width:300px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContent">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias accusamus, inventore aliquam in asperiores culpa libero recusandae, laboriosam ipsam illum non ipsum deserunt sequi nam nobis doloribus repellat quam quidem.</p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates impedit nostrum, magnam quibusdam deleniti aperiam in soluta placeat dolor pariatur deserunt aspernatur vero voluptatibus id suscipit possimus delectus aut neque!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla sapiente iusto ut vitae ullam accusamus provident debitis libero, tenetur quaerat molestias quidem doloremque beatae sunt saepe dolores soluta. Quia, soluta!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus ad minima maxime porro tenetur! Perspiciatis corrupti accusantium molestiae in! Eligendi ipsam minima aliquid laboriosam blanditiis recusandae sapiente, nobis officia ad.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium reprehenderit voluptates incidunt culpa? Dolore voluptatum ut possimus, fugit explicabo tenetur aperiam. Adipisci inventore quisquam architecto, fuga blanditiis voluptate labore minima?
  <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In atque doloremque, asperiores est nam vitae at labore ipsam perspiciatis ullam temporibus exercitationem dolorem inventore tenetur, saepe omnis alias quod distinctio!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis delectus nihil aliquam tempora fugit nam ea, temporibus quos deleniti libero explicabo quas neque exercitationem! Temporibus cum et hic porro deleniti?</p>
</div>

<div class="bruce_banner">
    <p style="text-align:center;">Banner, smash !</p>
</div>
```